# Connecting a surround system without jacks

Tags: wiring, speakers

I have recently bought a house which has already the sound cables passing through the walls. These are raw cables without any jack connectors.

My question is, when you go to buy a 5.1 surround system (or any speakers for that matter), what do you ask for when you do not want speakers with wires already connected.

Basically, when you have an AV receiver, there are jack inputs and there are also 'pure wired' inputs (where the cables are exposed). I want speakers which also accept this 'pure wired' inputs. I wish to know what these 'pure wired' inputs are called.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's two types that readily come to mind: spring terminals, and binding posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most sound systems have speakes with terminals and custom cables with a custom connector at one end and bare wire at the other. Just connect the speakers to the existing wires as usual, and connect the custom wires to the other end with soldering or with a screw terminal. I also have this configuration in my living room and it works perfectly.

Anyway, even if the speakers are hardwired to the device, you can still cut the wires and connect them to the installed wires with screw terminals.

And I believe the phrase you're looking for is "speaker terminal".